# Display message to User if URL does not exist 404 when downloading file using WebClient DownloadFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropbox, webclient, httpwebresponse

I have Dropbox shared links that get download to the client with the code below.

My issue is how do I know if the file exists on the Dropbox link. Below I have two links for testing. The first one is a shared link that is not shared anymore so if you plug that in to the URL it returns a 404 error. The second is a valid link and it downloads fine to the clients PC. You can try this links directly in the  browser.

I tried the code below but it stills returns an OK status and a 200 status for the broken link.

How can I let the user know that the link is broken 404 in the application?

```
     //Throws 404 error in browser. Linked was previously shared but now does not exits.  
     string URL = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0wnpjojvj6g4dx/Dropbox.pdf?raw=1"; 
      //Valid URL;
      string URL = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/javzmitc7ae4l6r/Dropbox.pdf?raw=1";

        HttpWebResponse response = null;
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Method = "HEAD"; //Also tried "GET"


            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                // get the status code
                HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode; //Always returns OK.

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(URL, location);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                /* A WebException will be thrown if the status of the response is not `200 OK` */
            }
            finally
            {
                // Don't forget to close your response.
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
```

**UPDATE**
Here is what I did to get it working and checking for a bad URL.

```
  string contentType = null;
  if(contentType != "text/html; charset=utf-8")
  {
       using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
       {
            client.DownloadFile(URL, location);
        }
  }
  else
  {
      //Throw error to user
  }
```

Comment: Without testing the code, but looking at firebug, there are a few differences.  One, the bad link has a content type of `text/html` while the valid link contains a content type matching the file type (`application/pdf`).  Second, the valid link does a 302 to the actual file location while the invalid link just returns HTML.  Does a combination of those differences (sniff the response content type or I actually don't know how to detect a 302) help you in identifying a way to identify a valid file?

Comment: @Tommy that did it. Thanks for the idea. I added to my code, If the ContentType = "text/html" then do not proceed to Download the file.

Comment: Awesome! - I am going to leave this as just a comment since its probably sort of a "hack-ish" answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to throw an WebException or rethrow that you catch. In your web.config you can configure the page for each http error

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors>...
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** – My previous answer suggested how to capture the 404, but there actually isn't one.

The problem here is that the page is actually returning a 200, not a 404. I would consider this a bug on the Dropbox side.

Comment: I have that in the code above. The problem is that GetResponse is not throwing an exception even tho the page is 404.

Comment: Then, it's not really returning 404. The view Dropbox is showing you in the browser or such may say 404, but the actual status code of the response is 200. In other words, if it's not actually returning a 404 status code on a 404, all you can do is reach out to Dropbox and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Confirmed: the page for the first URL is actually returning a 200.

Comment: Correct. But it is a 404 in the actual web page.

Comment: The page has an image on it that says "404", but the page is *not* a 404. It's a 200. I've flagged this for the team at Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the web interface (which is designed for users to interact with directly), you should be using the API (designed for programs and interfaces to interact with directly) to download the file.  [According to DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files-GET), the API does indeed return a 404 when requesting a bad file.

Screen capture of the API reference (a lot to type)

[image]

Comment: It seems that Dropbox is aware of the issue. Even with the API is not possible. https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204362869-How-to-detect-an-invalid-share-URL-

Comment: This would work if you had access to the user's account and knew which file you were looking for, but this doesn't help when downloading via a share link.

Comment: Fair enough - I will leave this as perhaps they will update / improve in the future :/